# magento orders are not tracked by google after upgrading universal analytics

Tags: magento-1.7, google-analytics

After upgrading Googles Universal Analytics, magento orders are not tracked / converted.  We have checked the following options

1. added the track informations in
   **app/design/frontend/base/default/page/html/head.phtml**
2. Sytem/Configuration-> Sales->Google Api -> Enabled and Account
   number is given and
3. Ecommerce Tracking is on status in Google Analytics.  But the orders
   not tracked by google.

we are using magento 1.7.  Shall we need to add any other things?

Answer (score 9):

I have added the code in **success.phtml** file, it is workging fine.

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($this->getOrderId());
$total = $order->getGrandTotal();
$shipping = $order->getShippingAmount();
$tax = $order->getTaxAmount();
$store = Mage::app()->getStore();
$name = $store->getName();

$items = $order->getAllItems();
$item_details = array() ;
foreach($items as $item) {
$det = array() ;
$det['sku'] = $item->getSku() ;
$det['name'] = $item->getName() ;
$det['category'] = get_category_name($item->getProductId()) ;
$det['price'] = $item->getPrice() ;
$det['quantity'] = number_format($item->getQtyOrdered(), 0) ; 
array_push($item_details, $det) ; 

}

function get_category_name($productId) { 
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
$category_name = "" ;
$cats = $product->getCategoryIds();

$cnt = 0 ;
foreach ($cats as $category_id) {
$_cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id) ;
$cnt++ ;
if($cnt == count($cats)) 
$category_name.=$_cat->getName() ;
else 
$category_name.=$_cat->getName()."," ; 
} 
return $category_name ; 
}

function getItemJs(&$transId, &$item) {
return <<<HTML
ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
'id': '$transId',
'name': '{$item['name']}',
'sku': '{$item['sku']}',
'category': '{$item['category']}',
'price': '{$item['price']}',
'quantity': '{$item['quantity']}'
});
HTML;
}

?>
<script type="text/javascript">

ga('require', 'ecommerce', 'ecommerce.js'); // Load GA ecommerce plug-in.
ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {
'id': '<?php echo $this->getOrderId(); ?>', // Transaction ID. Required
'affiliation': '<?php echo $name ?>', // Affiliation or store name
'revenue': '<?php echo $total; ?>', // Grand Total
'shipping': '<?php echo $shipping; ?>', // Shipping
'tax': '<?php echo $tax; ?>' // Tax
});
// to get items
<?php
foreach ($item_details as &$item) {
echo getItemJs($this->getOrderId(), $item);
}
?>
ga('ecommerce:send');
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

see [How do I add universal analytics to my magento store?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4235/how-do-i-add-universal-analytics-to-my-magento-store)

Personally I'm using the fooman [google analtics plus extension](https://github.com/fooman/googleanalyticsplus)

Comment: I have followed the the link and checked which you gave.  Is it really need the extension?

Comment: It's probably the easiest way. It's on Connect if you're more comfortable with that, and the fooman homepage has a manual that tells you how to set up goal tracking in your analytics profile

Comment: Is google tag manager content is needed for universal analytics?

Comment: I have added the tracking code in success.phtml, using google analytics dev guide then it works good.