# Google Analytics stopped working after Magento update

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.6, google-analytics, google-api

I recently updated from Magento 1.6.2 to 1.9.2.1 and I noticed that Google Analytics stopped tracking the website since I updated.

[image]

I don't have a googleanalytics folder in my template, nor do I have googleanalytics.xml in my layout folder. I never had that either, so I don't think it should be necessary for my Google Analytics to work, right?

I looked in to tutorials like this one: https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/magento/magento_google_analytics.htm and I noticed that the Google API module in that picture has a lot more options than I have in mine, so maybe I should update the module?
[image]

Comment: One of the most recent version of Magento included a move to Google's Universal Analytics. I suggest making sure that your GA account is setup for that.

Answer (score 1):

I changed the Type to Universal Analytics and added the analytics code to my head.phtml based on the answer of this topic [How do I add universal analytics to my magento store?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4235/how-do-i-add-universal-analytics-to-my-magento-store) and it started working again!

Answer (score 1):

Go to following file

```
 app/design/frontend/<your_theme_package>/default/layout/googleanalytics.xml
```

Change following

```
<default>
        <!-- Mage_GoogleAnalytics -->
        <reference name="after_body_start">
            <block type="googleanalytics/ga" name="google_analytics" as="google_analytics" />
        </reference>
 </default>
```

to

```
<default>
     <!-- Mage_GoogleAnalytics -->
     <reference name="before_body_end">
        <block type="googleanalytics/ga" name="google_analytics" as="google_analytics" template="googleanalytics/ga.phtml" />
     </reference>
</default>
```

and move `googleanalytics/ga.phtml` file from `base` theme to `your theme`.
Now you should be able to see the Google analytics code in website webpage view source.