# How to put the Google Analytics code on the check-out page?

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout-page, google-analytics

```
Magento 1.9.4
Porto theme
```

I have a tracking Google Analytics code and suppose to put that on the check-out page. What is the best way to do that? Is the check-out page actually one of the CMS pages or CMS blocks?

UPDATED: This is a different code than what we have for just the Google Analytics account. I think it's for special tracking of specific campaigns so the code is different than what we normally use for Google Analytics as such.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add universal analytics to my magento store?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4235/how-do-i-add-universal-analytics-to-my-magento-store)

Answer (score 0):

If you go to System>Configuration>Sales>Google API you can enable Google Analytics and enter the code there. Here is a tutorial that outlines the process https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/magento-1/google-analytics/

Comment: Thank you for that - do you think it's possible that this is a different code than what we have for just the Google Analytics account? I think it's for special tracking of specific campaigns so the code is different than what we normally use for Google Analytics as such.

Comment: Whoops! I just saw that you are still on Magento 1.9. I updated my answer to reflect that

Answer (score 0):

Google tag manager would be the best way to do this. Once installed you can track all sorts of pages ( we use it for sales conversion for adwords etc)

I can't remember how we we added it (manualy or not), but there are extensions for it, eg
https://github.com/magepal/magento1-google-tag-manager